# How to edit table row inline in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, inline-editing

I would like to update a table cell value by click on that. I have tried in following way. But all the rows are getting affected instead of single row. I have given unique index but I don't know where I went wrong.

**HTML Code**

```
<html>
<body>
<tbody id="itemtab" style="width:100%;height:200px !important;font-size:12px">
    </tbody>
</body>
</html>
```

**Jquery Code**

```
$("body").on('click','#btn',function(e){
        var box=$(this).text();
        console.log("Box Number to scan item code is: "+box);
        /*Check box is already scanned or not*/

         $.ajax({
             type : 'POST',
             url : '@routes.Application.isboxscanned()',
             data : {
                  content:box,
                  orgname:'Intel'

             }, 
             success : function(data) {

               console.log("flag"+data)

        if(data==2)
            {           

        console.log("Started Scanning through webservice");
        var k;
         $.ajax({
             type : 'POST',
             url : '@routes.Application.searchItemcodes()',
             data : {
                 boxnumber : boxnumber,    
                 orgname   : 'IN1005'                 
             },
             success : function(jsonp) {
                 $("#main").slideUp();
                 $("#itemscanning").slideDown();
                 $("#itemtab").empty();
                 var array = jsonp.data; 
                 $("#boxnum").text(boxnumber)
                 k=array.length;
                 for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
                     console.log(array[i].documentno);
                     console.log(array[i].upc);
                      console.log(array[i].itemcode);
                      console.log(array[i].modelname);
                      console.log(array[i].quantity);
                      if(jsonp.data=="noresult")
                        {
                                 $('#boxmsg').show();                   
                        }
                      else{
                      var table = '<tr class="active" style="height:40px;font-weight:bold">';
                          table+= '<td><input   type="checkbox" checked disabled /></td>'
                         table += '<td id='+k+'>'+k+'</td>';
                          table += '<td id='+array[i].documentno+'>'+array[i].documentno+'</td>';
                          table += '<td id='+array[i].upc+'>'+array[i].upc+'</td>';
                          table += '<td id='+array[i].itemcode+'>'+array[i].itemcode+'</td>';
                          table += '<td> '+array[i].modelname+'</td>';
                          table += '<td>' + array[i].quantity + '</td>';
                          table += '<td id="my'+k+array[i].itemcode+'" class="editable">' + array[i].quantity + '</td>';
                          table += '</tr>';
                          $row = table;   

                      k=k-1;
                      $("#itemtab").prepend($row);
                 }
                    } 



             },
             error : function() {

                 alert("Error IN UP")
             }

             });
            }
        else
            {
            console.log("Search in Localdb");

             $.ajax({
                 type : 'POST',
                 url : '@routes.Application.getitemsfromlocal()',
                 data : {
                     boxnum:box

                 },
                 success : function(data) {
                     $("#main").slideUp();
                     $("#itemscanning").slideDown();
                     $("#itemtab").empty();
                     $("#boxnum").text(box)
                     $.each(data, function(m, item) {                        
                          var table = '<tr class="active" style="height:40px;font-weight:bold">';
                             table+= '<td><input type="checkbox" checked disabled/></td>'
                             table += '<td id='+item[0]+'>'+item[0].trim()+'</td>';
                             table += '<td id='+item[1]+'>'+item[1].trim()+'</td>';
                              table += '<td id='+item[2]+'>'+item[2].trim()+'</td>';
                              table += '<td id='+item[3]+'>'+item[3].trim()+'</td>';
                              table += '<td> '+item[4]+'</td>';
                              table += '<td>' + item[5] + '</td>';
                              table += '<td id="myid'+k+item[3].trim()+'" class="editable">' + item[6] + '</td>';
                              table += '</tr>';
                              $row = table;   


                          $("#itemtab").prepend($row);
                        }); 

               },
                 error : function() {

                     console.log("Error in Searching Local DB");
                 }


                 });

            }
             },
             error : function() {
            console.log("errr");

             }
         });
$("#itemtab").on('click','.editable',function(e){ //assign event to editableTD class
        var i=0;
        var id=$(this).attr('id');
           e.stopPropagation();      //<-------stop the bubbling of the event here
           var value = $('#'+id).html();

          console.log(id+i);

          updateVal('#'+id, value);

        });


    function updateVal(currentEle, value) {
        console.log("Current Element is"+currentEle);
      $(currentEle).html('<input class="thVal" maxlength="4" type="text" width="2" value="0" />');
      $(".thVal").focus();
      $(".thVal").keyup(function (event) {
          if (event.keyCode == 13) {
           $(currentEle).html($(".thVal").val().trim());
           //$(currentEle).html($(".thVal").val().trim());


          }

      });

      $(document).click(function () { // you can use $('html')
            $(currentEle).html($(".thVal").val().trim());
      });
    }
```

The above code is updating properly. But the problem is its updating value in all the rows. For example one column has 3 values namely 10,20,30. if i update 10 to 12 it is updating in all the column. Please look into this and provide solution

Comment: Could you please provide a http://jsfiddle.net/ of your code?

Comment: Have you considered to use `contenteditable` attribute instead? And e.g oninput event for any TD change: `$().on('input', function(){...});`  BTW, your posted HTML markup isn't valid

Comment: Here is my jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/8acoz3fv/ Please help me @ProgrammerV5

Comment: I just tried your code and it is not updating the same value in the entire column it is working as expected so I can think of a couple of issues, the first one is that you are jsfiddle is not the exact same code as your application code (check very careful) or that you are using a different OS/Browser than the one I'm using, also, check that you using the same JS files that you used on the Jsfiddle example in your application.

Comment: Yes. Not exact code . Because I am populating values dynamically so I have made mirror functionality as like as my application code. I am using Ubuntu and my browser is crome. Please try to file different combinations in the fiddle example. for example update first value followed by middle value. Middle value is getting updated in all column cells. Please let me know the solution for this or if you know any other method to achieve  the same let me know @ProgrammerV5

Comment: I've tried several several different ways and I can't replicate your issue. I think the problem is somewhere else, is not the jquery code having an issue, I think is the way you are handling the ajax callback.